# How to pass environment variable that contains multiple & characters via the command line, in Cypress?

Tags: command-line-interface, cypress

I am trying to pass the value `abc&def&ghi` as an environment variable, via the command line, in my Cypress test.

Here is the command I am trying to run:

`npx cypress open --env password=abc&def&ghi`

When I run the above, I get this console error:

> The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved
> for future use; wrap an ampersand in double       quotation marks
> ("&") to pass it as part of a string.

So I updated my command to have double quotes around the & characters like so:

`npx cypress open --env password=abc"&"def"&"ghi`

However, with the above command the password is being read as only `abc`:

[image]

I assume I may need to enter an escape character or something like that.

I've tried adding double & single quotation marks around the password when passing it in too, but so far I have only been able to read it in as `abc`

Can someone please tell me how I can pass `abc&def&ghi` as an environment variable, so it can be read it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap it in `"` to send the entire text as a string.

```js
npx cypress open --env password="abc&def&ghi"
```

Test:

```js
cy.log(Cypress.env("password"))
```

Command:

```js
npx cypress open --env password="abc&def&ghi"
```

Test Runner:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed solution. However, when I run `npx cypress open --env configFile=QA,password="abc&def&ghi"`, & log it using `cy.log(Cypress.env("password"))`, `abc` is still only being returned for some reason. I'm using Cypress version 8.3.0 if that would have any impact

Comment: what is the name of your config file with extension? Also for cypress config you have to use the flag `--config-file`. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Overriding-Options

Comment: So I try `npx cypress open --config-file cypress/config/qa.json --env password="abc&def&ghi"`, but still getting same result